# The countable dense subset of every compact metric space

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, compactness

> Show  that  any   *compact*  metric  space  has  a  countable  dense subset.

I am having problem with finishing the proof  after a few steps. This is how I am going **:**

So, let  $X$ be the compact metric space . For every $n\in \Bbb N$,consider  the  $1\over n$ balls  of the points of $X$.Since compact , finitely many such balls  would  cover $X.$ So , let for a fixed $n,$ $$X\subset B\left({x_1}_n,{1\over n}\right)\cup B\left({x_2}_n,{1\over n}\right)\cup B\left({x_3}_n,{1\over n}\right).....B\left({x_k}_n,{1\over n}\right)$$

Now set $$\mathcal S=\{{x_i}_n|n\in\Bbb N;i=1,2,...,k; \text{where $k_n$ balls as above are required to cover $X$}\}$$

Since every $k_n$ is finite,the set $\mathcal S$ being countable union of finite sets is countable. So $|\mathcal S|=\aleph_0.$ My guess is that this $\mathcal S$  is the required *countable dense set. $[$ Because finite number of balls with them $\{x_{i_n} \}$  with  centers will cover the whole space  and every point will be in some or the other ball so they have to have at least one of them in any of their neighborhoods. $]$  But I'm struggling to  write  down the    rest  of  the proof.

Like if  I  take  any  point $z\in X$  and  any  $1\over n$ ball centered at $z$ , how do I show  that  one  of  the  $\{{x_n}_i\}$  is  in  that  ball $?$ That will  prove  the  density  of  the  set  $\mathcal S$  , right $?$

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: The distance is symmetric. So $x_{ni} \in B(z,1/n) \iff z \in B(x_{ni},1/n)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Thanks. Now that looks really  easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what Daniel Fischer  wrote ,*distance is symmetric* .

So, when you choose any arbitrary point $z\in X$ and choose an arbitrary nbd $\mathcal N$ of $z$ . then  $\exists$ $n$  such  that  $B(z,{1\over n})\subset \mathcal N$ . Now take  the  $1\over n$  balls  of $X$ that cover $X$. $z$ must be in one of the balls , say $B({x_i}_n,{1\over n})$ Then notice that  $d({x_i}_n,z)\lt {1\over n}$  which implies that $${x_i}_n\in B(z,{1\over n})$$. Thus proving that every point $z$ of $X$  is a limit point of the set $\mathcal S$ , i.e. $\mathcal S$  is  dense  in $X$.

So , we have our *countable dense* subset .